# Mounting Windows share on startup without storing password in plain text

Tags: rhel, automounting, fstab

I have the following in my `/etc/fstab` on a Red Hat 5 system:

```
//share/folder /mnt/folder cifs username=<my username>,password=<my password>,ro,soft,nounix
```

Can I replace this with something that will still mount `//share/folder` on my Linux box on startup without storing my plain text password in fstab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a separate file with the following lines, and make it readable by root only:

```
username=<my username>
password=<my password>
```

Then in `/etc/fstab`, replace the `username` and `password` options with:

```
credentials=/path/to/your/file
```

Comment: Still plain text, but better than nothing.